# Comparing sigma algebras

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Say we have two measurables functions $f$ and $g$ between two measurables spaces $(X,\mathcal A)$ and $(Y,\mathcal B)$

So $f : (X,\mathcal A) \to (Y, \mathcal B)$ and $g : (X,\mathcal A) \to (Y, \mathcal B)$

Now suppose that these functions verify some properties

function $f$ verifies property $1$ and property $2$ , whereas function $g$ only verifies property $1$

Is it correct to say that the sigma algebra generated by $g$, $g^{-1}(\mathcal B)$ will be included in the sigma algebra generated by $f$, $f^{-1}(\mathcal B)$ ?

I think (if it is correct) that I get some sort of intuition behind this : since $f$ is more constrained than $g$ , knowing the value of $f$ will tell us more about the antecedents of $f$, thus we have larger $f^{-1}(\mathcal B)$, corresponding to each value of $f$, in a probabilitic sense we will get more "information"

However I am not sure about this, and most importantly, I do not know how to prove it rigorously

Comment: In the generality that you state it, this is definitely not true (for example, if property 1 and property 2 both simplify say "$1=1$"), so you need to be more specific about the kind of properties you are thinking about.

Comment: What sort of properties are you thinking of? If $f$ and $g$ satisfy the property of being non-negative, and furthermore $f$ is constant, then $\sigma(f) = \{ \emptyset, X \}$ is likely much smaller than $\sigma(g)$.